# Spring boot controller with xsd

Tags: java, spring-boot, xsd-validation

I am very new in Spring boot ans xml.

So I have an xsd file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="ggg"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="ggg">    



<xsd:simpleType name="JustAString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="1" />
        <xsd:pattern value=".*[^\s].*" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="person">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="tns:JustAString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="Surname" type="tns:JustAString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="SecondName" type="tns:JustAString" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>  

 <xsd:complexType name="persons">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Person" type="tns:pserson" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType> 

</xsd:schema>
```

I also have a ready Java class Person

```
public class Person(){
    String name;
    String surname;
    String secondName;
    .... gettes and setters
}
```

So I need to create an annotation-based XML-Controller based on Spring boot that accepts an XML, validates it with my schema and than saves an object into DB.

I cannot undestand how do I organize this validation part and how can I map my xml schema into my java classes. The fields in XML and the fields in Java differ from each other: for example *SecondName* in XSD and *secondName* in Java.

Is it possible and how?